# Will I be allowed to board if my Schengen visa won't be valid when my flight departs?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland

My Schengen visa will be valid on 01 July but I have a flight on 30 June at 22:00. Technically, my visa is not valid when I get on my flight but will be valid when I get to the country. My arrival will be at 00:30. Is that okay or will it be a problem? I'm flying to Poland on WizzAir.

Comment: @200_success That's not the one. That question is about arriving before the visa is valid and waiting before passing through immigration; in this question, the visa will be valid at the time of landing but not at take-off.

Comment: @200_success I should have looked in the "Related questions" section!

Comment: You may have issues with border guards at departure side, depending on where you are, but definitely not on the arrival side.

Answer (score 15):

The border guards will only care whether your visa is valid *at the time you actually enter the Schengen area*. It should not matter how long time you have been traveling by then to *get* there.

There might be a risk that the airline's check-in/boarding agents at wherever you depart from could be unaware of how the rules work, and therefore try to deny you boarding. This *should* not happen, but it might be best to ask the airline in advance what their policy in these cases is.

Comment: Do you know what happens if his flight gets in 45 minutes early?

Comment: @IainGalloway A 2 1/2 hour flight being 45 minutes early? This seems highly unlikely to me. Even more, you might have to pick up your luggage and actually go to the immigration counter, which in many airports needs some time as well. And if even after all that you are still there before midnight I guess simply explaining the issue to the border police people will be a non-issue. The worst they will probably do is let you wait until the clock strikes midnight.

Comment: @dirkk I agree that such a short flight is unlikely to be substantially early. But I'm pretty sure that all the airports I've visited (in Europe, north America and Japan) have required me to pass through immigration _before_ collecting my checked luggage.

Comment: Can the airline deny you boarding for this reason? If it happened to me, I would demand compensation with every legal way I can.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: If "can" refers to physical ability, then they _can_ deny you boarding for any good or bad reason, or for no reason. If their reason is sufficiently bad, you may be able to win a legal fight afterwards, but the outcome is still that you won't be flying _that day_. So it makes sense to take some precautions against such a mistake happening, to the extent you have any precautions to take.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right, can't remember standing with my luggage at an immigration counter either. Sorry, wish I could edit my comment :(

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Note that airline policies are valid even if they're more stringent than underlying legal requirements. If the airline refuses boarding because they have a policy that the visa must be valid at the time of boarding, then there's nothing you can do, even if the receiving country would be fine with it. As visa start/duration is out of the hands of the airline (and nominally in the passenger's control), the airline owes you nothing if you don't follow officially posted requirements. - (Agents misinterpreting the policy is another thing.)